# Where did my branch go?

Tags: git

So on Git:

First I did a `git clone`  and checkout the Master.
Then I wanted to create a branch for myself so I did a `git checkout -b nameThatIForgot`
but I hadn't made any changes to it, no commits, etc.... nothing.

Then later today I deleted the whole folder and recloned the git repo.

So now I don't have that branch anymore? It is alright if it is gone, just wanted to make sure I am not creating an extra branch if the previous one still exists.

Comment: *Please,* could you read at least some introductory text (or, better, [a book](http://git-scm.com/book)) before starting dabbling with a complex tool? A DVCS is conceptually simple, but these concepts must be studied and understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your branch is gone. Local branches are stored inside the `.git` folder of the repository. If you delete it, everything is lost (unless you have pushed to another repo).

Answer (score 4):

If you did not push the branch to the remote repository, then it only ever existed locally.  When you removed your clone, you removed the local branch along with it.